# Writing Factor Analysis output to file

Tags: r

I am doing a factor analysis via the psych-package, which generates quite some output `fa8<-fa(corMat, nfactors=8, ...)`

The output includes some matrices and some text information. However, I did not find a good way of saving the matrices of the output to a file. So far, I was able to dump the data via `sink("foo.txt"); f8; sink()` as complete output. Neither `write(fa8)` nor `write.csv(fa8)` work, because the class of the output is a vector - it does not contain the matrix data itself, though.

Any suggestions on how I can get the fa-matrix itself for further analysis and saving it to a file?

**update #1:**
An examplatory output of `fa(corMat, nfactors=2, ...)`would be

```
Factor Analysis using method =  pa
Call: fa(r = corMat, nfactors = 2, rotate = "oblimin", fm = "pa")
Standardized loadings based upon correlation matrix
       PA1   PA2   h2    u2
BIO   0.86  0.02 0.75 0.255
GEO   0.78  0.05 0.63 0.369
CHEM  0.87 -0.05 0.75 0.253
ALG  -0.04  0.81 0.65 0.354
CALC  0.01  0.96 0.92 0.081
STAT  0.13  0.50 0.29 0.709

                PA1  PA2
SS loadings    2.14 1.84
Proportion Var 0.36 0.31
Cumulative Var 0.36 0.66

 With factor correlations of 
     PA1  PA2
PA1 1.00 0.21
PA2 0.21 1.00

Test of the hypothesis that 2 factors are sufficient.

The degrees of freedom for the null model are  15  and the objective function was  2.87
The degrees of freedom for the model are 4  and the objective function was  0.01 

The root mean square of the residuals is  0.01 
The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  0.02 

Fit based upon off diagonal values = 1
Measures of factor score adequacy             
                                                PA1  PA2
Correlation of scores with factors             0.94 0.96
Multiple R square of scores with factors       0.88 0.93
Minimum correlation of possible factor scores  0.77 0.86
```

*Source: http://rtutorialseries.blogspot.de/2011/10/r-tutorial-series-exploratory-factor.html*

The question is: How do I get the standardized loadings matrix in the output for further analysis?

Comment: Is your question "how do I save a matrix to a file?" or is it "how do I extract a matrix from a list returned by a function?"

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for the comment - I've extended my question. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: If you want the matrix without the attributes you can use `fa.out$loadings[]` [where fa.out contain the results of your `fa` call]. If you want to write the matrix to a file yo can use the previous way or even `write.csv(loadings(fa.out), 'fa.out.csv')`